# How to fix import error when importing python module from different directories

Tags: python-3.x, python-import

I have a few directories in my python project.

```
|--main.py
|--sideproject/
|           |--sub_main.py
|           |--test.py
|           |--__init__.py
```

sub_main is needed in main but an error happens on sub_main's import of test.py

the following code works when running sub_main but when main.py imports sub_main, the function breaks saying "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'test"

```
from test import *
```

By changing it to `from .test import *` main.py works but sub_main will not.

I have tried adding a blank `__init__.py` like some have mentioned, but nothing seems to work.

Comment: You will have to import each .py files, unless you code in your main.py to access the sideproject folder then call the files your need.

Since you are only calling test.py

Answer (score 0):

Here's a (not-so-clean) way.

```
|--main.py
|--sideproject/
|           |--sub_main.py
|           |--test.py
|           |--__init__.py
```

In **main.py:**

```
from sideproject import sub_main    

def func_in_main():
    return sub_main.func_in_sub_main()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(func_in_main())
```

In **sub_main.py:**

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    # If sub_main is run directly.
    # Use regular imports.

    import test
    print(test.func_in_test())
else:
    # If sub_main is imported by main.
    # Need to do imports relative to package.

    from . import test
    def func_in_sub_main():
        return(test.func_in_test())
```

In **test.py:**

```
__all__ = ["func_in_test"]    

def func_in_test():
    return 123
```

In **init.py:** (empty)

**result:**

```
gino:test$ ls
total 8
-rw-rw-r-- 1 gino gino  150  1月 24 09:05 main.py
drwxrwxr-x 3 gino gino 4096  1月 24 08:57 sideproject
gino:test$ python3 main.py
123
gino:test$ cd sideproject
gino:test$ python3 sub_main.py
123
```

---

But I would suggest thinking about why you need to run *sub_main* directly. I recommend to consider structuring *sideproject* as a package, using *sub_main* as a sort of public API declaration (or declaring the public APIs in ***init**.py*) then always running your app from *main.py* (importing *sideproject*).